# ASP.NET MVC RenderAction Best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to render a partial view (B) onto a View (A) using RenderAction, I can either pass the model from A to B and populate a property on AModel with the required data for B:

```
Html.RenderAction("action", "controller", new { model = ViewData.Model })
```

Or just pass the action and controller and leave the action to be responsible for getting the data it requires:

```
Html.RenderAction("action", "controller”)
```

My question is, which approach is considered to be best practice? Should all data be on the parent model or should the parent be as lightweight as possible with partial views returning their own models specific to their data requirements? Are both approaches equally acceptable, or is there a better way entirely?
Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: why don't you use RenderPartial method?

Comment: `RenderPartial` method doesn't hit controller action it generally used for showing static html data...@aleha

Comment: I guess RenderPartial is just as valid as it accepts a model arg, however it doesnt answer the question of best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading partial views with `Html.RenderAction("action", "controller")` then in my opinion take a separate model for your partial view because if you have separate model for partial view then you can easily use partial views where ever you want in other views also and your view model will be less bulky and you have separate lightweight models for your views and partialviews.

Comment: @jondow..actually your question is opinion based and as far as RenderPartial is concerned it is helpfull when your model is already binded because it doesn't have controller action to bind new data.